# How can Android playback streaming audio by push notification trigger?

Tags: android

I'm an iOS app developer and not familiar with Android. I'd like to implement the feature that playbacks audio over the internet when the mobile receives a push notification.

I've investigated it for iOS and concluded that it is impossible in iOS because Apple prohibits downloading data over the internet in background from being developed.

I'd like to know if this feature is feasible or not in Android. Could you give me any advises ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement [PendingIntent](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/navigation) to get you notification and start [ForgroundService](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FbpD5RZtbCc) or [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) or [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/effective-foreground-services-on-android_11.html) to play your audio and close it when the user leaves your app or while they are using your app depending your particular needs.